# Brigde HTML login with Json

Tags: html, json, authentication, bridge

I want to write a HTML webpage, which can be used to login to another already existing website. It is secured by a json login section. I want to send the data entered into my website to the second website and receive the answer. Is this possible to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use web service or javascript fot this work.